# Subtracting fields from two different tables and updating the value during update in Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, angularjs, laravel

I have two different tables, table_employee and table_leave. table_employee contains fields such as emp_id, paid_vacation(In Hours), used_vacation(in Hours), while table_leave contains id, hours_spent(in Hours). please how can i deduct the hours_spent in the table_leave from used from the paid_vacation in the table_employee and then update the used_vacation in table_employee with the new value

for instance. paid_vacation =150 hours, used_vacation = 0, hours_spent= 8 hours, with this, this used_vacation should be updated to 150 -8 hours = 142 hours left. I want deduct and update back in the table.

```
private function saveEmployeeLeave(Request $request, $id=null){
    
    if($id != NULL){
        $employeeId = DB::table('as_tbl_employee_master')
                            ->where('employee_id', $request->employee_id)
                            ->get();
    }
    $employee_id = $request->employee_id;
    $paid_vacation = $request->paid_vacation;
    $used_vacation = $request->used_vacation;

    $empData = new AsEmployee();
    if($id !== null) {
        $empData = AsEmployee::find($id);
        if($empData == null) {
            $errors = array('Id: ' . $id . ' not exist');
            return json_encode([], 400, 'Failed', $errors);
        }
    }
    $empData->employee_id = $employee_id;
    $empData->paid_vacation = $paid_vacation;
    $empData->used_vacation = $used_vacation;
    $empData->save();
    // $emp_id = $request->emp_id;
    $emp_id = $request->emp_id;
    $dept = $request->department_id;
    $english_name = $request->english_name;
    $department = $request->department;
    $selectedLeaveType = $request->selectedLeaveType;
    $application_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $date_from = $request->date_from;
    $date_to = $request->date_to;
    $comment = $request->comment;
    $contact = $request->contact;
    $hours = $request->hours;
    $approval_emp_id = $request->reports_to;
    $manager = $request->manager;
    $status = $request->status;
    $empInfo = new AsEmployeeLeave();
    if($id !== null) {
        $empInfo = AsEmployeeLeave::find($id);
        if($empInfo == null) {
            $errors = array('Id: ' . $id . ' not exist');
            return json_encode([], 400, 'Failed', $errors);
        }
    }
    $empInfo->emp_id = $emp_id;
    $empInfo->department_id = $dept;
    $empInfo->application_time = $application_time;
    $empInfo->type = $selectedLeaveType;
    $empInfo->date_from = $date_from;
    $empInfo->date_to = $date_to;
    $empInfo->comment = $comment;
    $empInfo->requester_emp_id = $emp_id;
    $empInfo->requester_sign = $english_name;
    $empInfo->approval_emp_id = $approval_emp_id;
    $empInfo->approval_sign = $manager;
    $empInfo->contact = $contact;
    $empInfo->hours = $hours;
    $empInfo->status = $status;
    $empInfo->save();
    return $empData;
}
```

I called it inside this function

```
    public function addEmpLeave(Request $request){
    $responseData = $this->saveEmployeeLeave($request);
    return ($responseData instanceof JsonResponse) ? $responseData : $this->sendResponse($responseData);
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @kerbh0lz, sure i wrote the code but i am stuck in the middle of the code, that is why i need assistance, Thank you. I will paste my code for you to see

Comment: @Francis, post your update controller

Comment: Thanks @TalhaF. i just called the function using with the api, and when i click update from the UI, it should called the function

Comment: are you still finding the solution?

Comment: @STA, NOT YET, ANY HELP PLEASE

Comment: @Francis I answered your queation. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private function saveEmployeeLeave(Request $request, $id=null){
    
    if($id != NULL){
        $employeeId = DB::table('as_tbl_employee_master')
                            ->where('employee_id', $request->employee_id)
                            ->get();
    }
    $employee_id = $request->employee_id;
    $paid_vacation = $request->paid_vacation;
    $used_vacation = $request->used_vacation;

    $empData = new AsEmployee();
    if($id !== null) {
        $empData = AsEmployee::find($id);
        if($empData == null) {
            $errors = array('Id: ' . $id . ' not exist');
            return json_encode([], 400, 'Failed', $errors);
        }
    }
    $empData->employee_id = $employee_id;
    $empData->paid_vacation = $paid_vacation;
    $empData->used_vacation = $used_vacation;
    $empData->save();
    // $emp_id = $request->emp_id;
    $emp_id = $request->emp_id;
    $dept = $request->department_id;
    $english_name = $request->english_name;
    $department = $request->department;
    $selectedLeaveType = $request->selectedLeaveType;
    $application_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $date_from = $request->date_from;
    $date_to = $request->date_to;
    $comment = $request->comment;
    $contact = $request->contact;
    $hours = $request->hours;
    $approval_emp_id = $request->reports_to;
    $manager = $request->manager;
    $status = $request->status;
    $empInfo = new AsEmployeeLeave();
    if($id !== null) {
        $empInfo = AsEmployeeLeave::find($id);
        if($empInfo == null) {
            $errors = array('Id: ' . $id . ' not exist');
            return json_encode([], 400, 'Failed', $errors);
        }
    }
    $empInfo->emp_id = $emp_id;
    $empInfo->department_id = $dept;
    $empInfo->application_time = $application_time;
    $empInfo->type = $selectedLeaveType;
    $empInfo->date_from = $date_from;
    $empInfo->date_to = $date_to;
    $empInfo->comment = $comment;
    $empInfo->requester_emp_id = $emp_id;
    $empInfo->requester_sign = $english_name;
    $empInfo->approval_emp_id = $approval_emp_id;
    $empInfo->approval_sign = $manager;
    $empInfo->contact = $contact;
    $empInfo->hours = $hours;
    $empInfo->status = $status;
    $empInfo->save();

    $empData = AsEmployee::find($empData->id);
    $empData->used_vacation = (int)$paid_vacation - (int)$hours;
    $empData->save();

    return $empData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @STA, I think this should work but i sorted it out, Thanks alot